# Rails run code after transactional unit test rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I have a test suite, and after it runs, I want to execute some code AFTER the `teardown` does not work; I already tried.

I believe it doesn't work because when it runs, the transactional changes to the database have not been rolled back yet.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I'm using `ActiveSupport:TestCase` if that matters.

Comment: What's code do you want to execute?

Comment: What's the current code in the teardown? What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error, or some unexpected behaviour? What are "the transactional changes to the database" that you expect to have rolled back? How are you expecting those to be rolled back?

Comment: There's an easy way to explain all of this, fully.... **show us the code**. A vague description of the code is not massively helpful; seeing the real code is.